# Damped and forced periodic vibrations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we view the ODE as $mx''+cx'+kx=F(t)$ and the complementary portion, x_c, of the general solution $x=x_c+x_p$ is sometimes denoted by $x_{tr}$. What does the notation indicate about the overall long-term effect on the general solution $x=x_c+x_p$ regardless of the initial conditions?

My intuition tells me that it stays constant and has no effect over the long term behavior of a forced or damped periodic? If I am way off why? Can someone show this visually?

Comment: What do you mean by complementary portion $x_c$ ? The solution of the homogeneous equation?

Comment: Yes the complimentary solution is the solution to the homogeneous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all constants $m,c,k$ are positive the homogeneous solution is given by
$$ x_c(t) =  e^{-\frac{c}{2m}t}(a_1 e^{\frac{\sqrt{c^2-4mk}}{2m}t} + a_2e^{-\frac{\sqrt{c^2-4mk}}{2m}t}) $$
now regardless of the sign of $c^2-4mk$, $x_c(t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$, meaning that $x_p(t)$ is going to be the dominant part in determining the dynamics of $x(t)$.